# Shopify + Python library: how to create new shipping address

Tags: python, shopify

I'm having troubles adding a new shipping address by using the Python API.

Let's put aside the auth part and assume I have the customer_id.

I couldn't find how to put the correct lines of code to achieve this goal.
I've searched the shopify tests folder but couldn't find such example there.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Are your using the official [ShopifyAPI](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) library for python?

Comment: Yes...I couldn't find a way to add an address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is currently no `CustomerAddress` resource implemented into the official python Shopify API client, you can append the address information directly onto the `addresses` attribute of the `Customer` resource as a work-around:

```
customer_id = 1234567890

new_address = {
    "address1": "123 Main Street",
    "address2": "#5",
    "city": "New York",
    "company": "",
    "country": "United States",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "phone": "",
    "province": "New York",
    "zip": "10001"
 }

customer = shopify.Customer.find(customer_id)
customer.addresses.append(new_address)
customer.save()
```